# Shell script: using variables adds carriage return

Tags: shell, variables, sh, synology

I'm running the following shell script on a *Synology DSM 6*:

```
DATE=`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S`
/usr/local/mariadb10/bin/mysqldump -u user -ppwd fm | 
gzip -c -9 > /volume1/homes/username/SOS_BU/Syn_MariaDB/fm_${DATE}.gz
```

The problem is that after execution, the filename has a carriage return left to the point. Example:

```
fm_20180113_125554[CR].gz
```

So, the file is created, but the filename causes trouble with a *CR* in it.

Anyone has an idea where the *CR* comes from and how I can avoid it?

Comment: Is it `CR`or `LF`? Did you `dos2unix`?

Comment: dos2unix solved it. Thank you very much! I didn't have that in mind, as the variable is right in the middle of the command line.